Why is this overflow not detected?
The item-outer-container element has a smaller width than its child div, so why doesn't a horizontal scrollbar appear?
https://jsfiddle.net/v32h5ko7/


#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(50%);
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  &>* {
    width: calc(100%/3);
  }
}

span {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#blu-button-container {
  flex-shrink: 1;

  span {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

#title {
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#item-outer-container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;

  div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: end;
    gap: 5px;

    span {
      width: 40px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
<div id=container>
  <div id=blu-button-container>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div id=title>TITLE</div>
  <div id=item-outer-container>
    <div>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




You need one more div wrapper inside #item-outer-container in order to dissociate container and child width.
https://jsfiddle.net/rdj29amL/#&togetherjs=zlfuJRNyqE
<div id=item-outer-container>
  <div width='100%'>
    <div>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


The problem is justify-content: end;. Remove it and it's functionality will be replaced with &>:first-child { margin-top: auto !important;}.
    #item-outer-container {
      overflow-x: auto;
      height: 50px;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;

      & > :first-child {
          margin-top: auto !important;   
      }
      ...
     }

This solution came up with some help from this answer: Use justify-content: flex-end and to have vertical scrollbar
The discussion is pointing to an old bug

if you think the solution is within another SO question, vote to close as duplicate instead of repeating the same answer

@Temani Afif - Is not 100% the same... I used it as help to offer the current answer, but the background is there... But thanks for downvote.

it's 1000% the same. from the duplicate: In summary, don't use justify-content: flex-end but rather put a margin-top: auto on the first child.. That's what you are doing.
